# Generic classes, constraints and inheritance

Tags: generics, typescript, typescript1.8

So I'm fairly new to Typescript, and also generics. I'm not sure if I found a bug/limitation of Typescript or I'm missing the correct pattern to do what I want.

I have a `Widget` generic base class that holds a value of type `T`. For example it could be `string`, `number`, whatever.

I want to have a `Widget` subclass that will hold an `Array<T>` as its value, eg `string[]`, `Date[]` etc.

Example consumer code:

```
let w = new Widget<string>();
w.value = "abc";

let aw = new ArrayWidget<number[]>();
aw.value = [1, 2, 3];
```

The closest I have come is this:

```js
class Widget<T> {
    public value:T;
}

class ArrayWidget<U extends T[], T> extends Widget<U> {
    setValue() {
        let v = new Array<T>();
        this.value = v; // error: Type 'T[]' is not assignable to type 'U'

    }
}

let aw = new ArrayWidget<string[], string>();
aw.value = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

How can I specify that `ArrayWidget`'s generic class is actually an array of `<T>`? Currently I have to explicitly cast like so:

```js
this.value = v as U;
```

And everything is happy (the consuming code works as expected). Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
class ArrayWidget<T> extends Widget<Array<T>> {
    setValue() {
        let v = new Array<T>();
        this.value = v; // ok
    }
}

let aw = new ArrayWidget<string>();
aw.value = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

It will save you from having to specify an additional generic parameter too.